# jQuery - Adding a hyphen inside string

Tags: jquery

I am pulling the text from a select box's options. Now I pass this string value to an append() function, but I want to add a hyphen to the string, for calling an image name:

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Demo Cars</option>
    <option>New Cars</option>
    <option>Used Cars</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

```
var p = 'http://myurl.com/images/';
$('select').eq(0).on('change',function(){
    $('#productQuote').empty();
    var j = $(this).children(':selected').val(); 
    $('#productQuote').append('<img src="'+ p + j + '.jpg' '" />');
});
```

For example:

If I choose the first select option, the string will be: "Demo Cars", and thus, j == "Demo Cars".

But now I want to call its image, and my image names are not allowed to have spaces inside them. 
**So, this begs the question, how do I add a hyphen between Demo and Cars?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `replace()` method. Using a regular expression with the global flag set will replace all spaces in the string with hyphens, even if there is more than one space:

```
var j = $(this).children(':selected').val().replace(/ /g, '-');
```

Comment: In tried this, but a word like "New Demo Cars" results in: "New-Demo Cars"...it does not take out the last space...

Comment: Sorry man, updated the wrong file - your code works. appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

Use replace() method:

```
var j = ...
j = j.replace(" ", "-");
```

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: thank you, but I tried all the solutions, my function does not work, even when I alert the value of j after the last code line, alert does not execute...it breaks somewhere inside the append() line

Comment: and Oh yes, what about a string with more than one space in it?

Comment: in that case use a regular expression with global modifier as in the @MattCain answer :) but as long as you have one single space use a replace with strings

Answer (score 1):

There are many simple ways to do this, each with different purpose at times. Here are a couple simple ways to do this "inline", without affecting much of your already usable code:

With [.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) (The downside is if you have more than one white space, it won't replace them all. This can be remidied with regex, as I'll show below, or split join)

```
 $('#productQuote').append('<img src="'+ p + j.replace(" ", "-") + '.jpg" />');
```

Replace ALL style:

```
$('#productQuote').append('<img src="'+ p + j.replace(/ /g, "-") + '.jpg" />');
```

With the team of [.split().join()](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/javascripts-dream-team-in-praise-of-split-and-join/)

```
$('#productQuote').append('<img src="'+ p + j.split(" ").join("-") + '.jpg" />');
```

Comment: thank you, but I tried all the solutions, my function does not work, even when I alert the value of j after the last code line, alert does not execute...it breaks somewhere inside the append() line

Comment: @DextrousDave I saw that, you "single quotes" were off, I fixed

Comment: I see your code does the same as Fabrizio's below - It only works for a string with one space in...what if you have a word like: "New Demo Cars"?

Comment: @DextrousDave NP, it was my fault for not double checking the whole string, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do this in JavaScript as it can be achieved in markup, the `<option>` tag has an attribute of `value` which is what you should be using, as this separates any logic and presentation data.

For example using the markup below would allow you to use the `.val()` method as you already are, but it would return the `value` rather than the text.

```
<select>
    <option value="demo-cars">Demo Cars</option>
    <option value="new-cars">New Cars</option>
    <option value="used-cars">Used Cars</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah this is a good observation, but this is used in wordpress, where the person who uploads the image do not know where to set any attributes of anything...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer
http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/6/

```
<div class="btn-post">button text</div>
<div id='test'> </div>


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#test').html($('.btn-post').text().replace(" ", "-"));
});
```

I hope this will helpful to you to achieve your request.